# What "clear git branch" command does?

Tags: git, command-line

I was working in VS Code terminal and instead of executing 2 consistent commands "clear" and "git branch" accidentally executed one "clear git branch" command. As a result I see something terrible: hundreds of "delete mode 100644 Databases/......", "create mode 100644 Databases/.....", "rename Api/..." output strings in my terminal. What actually happened and what has been done? What this command does? Should I delete this branch and recreate it from scratch to avoid its negative effect? Looks too much frighten.

Comment: If your git status still clean?

Comment: Yes, it shows only those files that were changed by me. And when I execute this "clear git branch" again nothing happens.

Comment: The `clear` bash command doesn't take arguments. `clear something` should output `clear` man hints.

Comment: I hope it did nothing but from where I got those terrible result? Before that I just created new branch, executed git pull, changed some files and before creating new commit tried to clear the screen and check the branch where I was in. When I noticed this strange command I scrolled the screen up and noticed a bunch of those output strings.

Comment: Oh, so the output which unsettled you was most probably coming from your git pull. I wouldn't worry too much is your status is now correct.

Comment: `clear` is not a Git command; it's some other command that does whatever it does. Probably, even with arguments, it simply tried to clear your screen.

Comment: Yes, I know that this is not a Git command and I have the same suggestion that it should be caused by git pull command. Thank you all.